# Unknown column 'chenzhen' in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP script that connects to a MySQL database using the mysqli extension to search for Blog Posts based on Username or ID. I created a VIEW called `BlogSearch` that uses joins form other tables to aggregate the information I need together that is represented like this:

The Tables it pulls from are called `Profiles` that has the User information, `BlogPosts` and `BlogCategory`

Everytime I search I get the error:
`Unknown column 'chenzhen' in 'where clause'`

The PHP code I'm using below:

```
require 'database.php'; 

        $query = "SELECT * FROM BlogSearch";

  echo <<<EOF
<form method='post' action='' style="padding: 30px 0;">
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="float: left;">
        <tr>
        <td>Search Blog Posts by Username/ID</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="search" name="search" style="width: 300px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Search" name="submit_button" style="float: right;" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
EOF;

        if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])) 
    {
        $search_term = $_POST['search'];
          $query = $query . " WHERE `NickName` LIKE '%$search_term%' OR ID = $search_term ";


        // run the query and store the results in the $result variable.
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    }

    if ($result) {

  // create a new form and then put the results
  // into a table.



  echo "<form method='post' action='delete.php' style='clear: both;'>"; 
  echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='15'>
        <th width='5%'>
        <input type='checkbox' id='allcb' onclick='checkAll(this)' name='allcb' />Check All
        </th>
        <th width='10%'>User</th>
        <th width='85%'>Blog Post Title</th>
        ";


  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

        $title = substr($row->PostCaption,0,50);
        $id = $row->PostID;
        $user = $row->NickName;

        //put each record into a new table row with a checkbox
    echo "<tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]'  value=$id />
            <td>$user</td>
            <td>$title</td>
         </tr>"; 

    }

    // when the loop is complete, close off the list.
    echo "</table><p><input id='delete' type='submit' class='button' name='delete' value='Delete Selected Items'/></p></form>";
}
```

I don't know why it's even identify the username as a column. Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element in an SQL query that isn't an SQL keyword or a literal (denoted by single quotes), is assumed to be an object (e.g. table, column) name.

Your problem is the missing quotes around `$search_term` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
$query = $query . " WHERE `NickName` LIKE '%$search_term%' OR ID = $search_term ";
```

You should add them, as thus:

```
$query = $query . " WHERE `NickName` LIKE '%$search_term%' OR ID = '$search_term' ";
```

Comment: Something so simple, yet i missed. Even though I did try many different variations, even using that method, it didn't work until now. Thanks alot it works!

Comment: Side Note qoute or not to qoute thats the question... if the table column type is an string type always use qoutes like '1' if your column type is an int type NEVER qoute.. MySQL is using converts to cast the datatype what will cause extra overhead or can cause useless indexes in some cases

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your **$search_term** in single quotes in where clause like this `'$search_term'`